# PHP : VS code + >Intelephense detect an error on references passed in foreach (and in functions)

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intelephense

VS Code detect errors on my php code when I try to use a reference in a foreach.
This should be possible refering to PHP doc :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
```

My code is exactly the same :

```
$ret = [1,2,3,4] ;
foreach ( $ret as &$v )
     $v = $v * 2 ;
```

but VS Code still show me errors on it, and I don't know how to remove these warnings (code is working)

Any idea why ? Thanks a lot for your help !

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

PS : i know this code is stupid, it's just an example.

Comment: Hmm it does not do that for me, although I am using `PHP Tools` I recently replaced `intelephence` for no obvious reason

Comment: Well it looks like i'm having problems with the & char,
I have an error on `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE) ;` too...
Unexpected 'Unknown' php

I tried to disable Intelephense and add PHP Tools and PHP Debug, no change for this but it seems to be better anyway, thanks !

Comment: I'm using Intelephense but can't reproduce that error when copy/pasting that snippet

Comment: Yes i'm starting to think it's probably not because of Intelephense... maybe something in the VSCode config but it's gonna by hard to find :|

Comment: Check on other Extensions that might be getting in the way

Comment: Also remember, this is not PHP checking your code. I assume it still runs, so it is something checking your syntax that is not up to the task

Comment: Out of interest, what version of PHP are you using

Comment: I'm also guessing that the error persists after you've saved the file? From time to time, it does tell me that I have some error even after I've fixed it, and doesn't disappear until I save the file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly php 8.1

Comment: @M.Eriksson yes i have this one since 2 days, even after a reboot :(

Comment: Note that using references in foreach loops can have some undesirable side effects: c.f. https://www.toptal.com/php/10-most-common-mistakes-php-programmers-make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was not a problem Intelephense, but with PHP IntelliSense :
https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-intellisense

Disabling it remove the errors i had.
I did not post an issue on intellisense Github.